# Why does a release build for Android fail while all others run through

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ ionic --version
3.19.1

$ cordova --version
8.0.0
```

Follow the ionic docs to the letter:

```
ionic start showbug blank
cd showbug
ionic generate component gaga
```

Then add `GagaComponent` to the declarations of `app.modules.ts`:

```
...
import { GagaComponent } from '../components/gaga/gaga';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    GagaComponent
  ],
...
```

Now the issue can be observed, but **only if** building a **release** for Android:

- `ionic serve` works
- `ionic cordova build android` works as expected
- `ionic cordova build android --release --prod` yields

  `typescript error
      Type GagaComponent in PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/components/gaga/gaga.ts is part
      of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
      PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/app/app.module.ts and ComponentsModule in
      PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/components/components.module.ts! Please consider moving
      GagaComponent in PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/components/gaga/gaga.ts to a higher
      module that imports AppModule in PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/app/app.module.ts and
      ComponentsModule in PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/components/components.module.ts.
      You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes GagaComponent in
      PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/components/gaga/gaga.ts then import that NgModule in
      AppModule in PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/app/app.module.ts and ComponentsModule in
      PATH_TO_APP/showbug/src/components/components.module.ts.`

Comment: Actually `--prod` is the culprit ...

Comment: no... your component is declared in component.module.ts.. you need to actually import the component module into app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 3, when you generate a component, it creates the component related ts and scss pages and also a `component.module.ts`.

The component will be declared in `component.module.ts`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GagaComponent,
    //any other generated components
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule
  ],
  exports: [
     GagaComponent,
    //any other generated components
  ]
})
```

You need to import this module to `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ComponentsModule,//here
  ],
```

Or you can set in imports in any of the page modules where you need to use it

Answer (score 0):

Remove `GagaComponent` from `declarations` of `component.module.ts`